Prove that $\mathrm{E} e^{i \xi \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n X_{m}}}=\exp (n \log \int_{\mathbb{R}} \cos \frac{\xi}{n x} f(x) d x)$
Problem. Suppose that the random variables $X_n$ are i.i.d, $f(x)$ is the continuous density of $X_n$ and support on $[-1,1]$, that is, $f(x)\ge0$ and $f(x)\le M$.
I want to show that
$$
\lim _{n \to \infty}\mathrm{E}\exp\left({\rm i}\xi
\sum_{m = 1}^{n}
\frac{1}{nX_{m}}\right) =
\exp\left(n\log\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}
\cos\left(\frac{\xi}{n x}\right)
\operatorname{f}\left(x\right)\,
{\rm d x}\right)\right)
$$

My attempt:
I have proven that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\exp (n \log \int_{\mathbb{R}} \cos \frac{\xi}{n x} f(x) d x)=\exp(-c|\xi|)$ for some c.
Since $\mathrm{E} e^{i \xi \sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n X_{m}}}=(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos\frac{\xi}{n x} f(x) d x+i\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sin\frac{\xi}{n x} f(x) d x)^n$
I don't know how to analyze the imaginary part, and I can only prove that the module of $\mathrm{E} e^{i \xi \sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n X_{m}}}$ will tend to $\exp(-c|\xi|)$.
I prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sin\frac{\xi}{n x} f(x) d x \sim Clog(n)/n$, and the Arg of the limit will be $\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{ilog(n)}$, which does not exist I think.

More precisely
Let $A_n=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\cos\frac{\xi}{n x} f(x) d x$, $B_n=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\sin\frac{\xi}{n x} f(x) d x$, then I get:
$$A_n \to 1-\frac{-c|\xi|}{n}, B_n \sim \frac{C_1log(n)+C_2}{n}$$
Then we get
$$(A_n+iB_n)^n=\sqrt{A_n^2+B_n^2} e^{in*\theta _n}$$
I proved that $\sqrt{A_n^2+B_n^2} \to e^{-c|\xi|}$, but  $$\theta _n = arctan(\frac{B_n}{A_n})\sim arctan(\frac{\frac{C_1log(n)+C_2}{n}}{1-\frac{-c|\xi|}{n}})\sim \frac{\frac{C_1log(n)+C_2}{n}}{1-\frac{-c|\xi|}{n}}$$
So $e^{in*\theta _n} \sim e^{i(C_1log(n)+C_2)}$, which will not converge.
So I am confused. Any comments will be appreciated.

Maybe there is a missing condition: $f(x)$ should be symmetric about $0$, but I am not sure.

Why are you taking limits in $n$, if you want to show this is true for all $n$?

$\sum_{m\geq 1}X_m^{-1}$ is not well defined (a random walk does not converge at all)

What is $n$? Is it just a fixed parameter? If so, why is it inside the sum? Why not just absorb $n$ into the definition of $\xi$, i.e. define $\xi' = \xi/n$? Is your first sum supposed to go from $m = 1$ to $m = n$ instead of to $m = \infty$?

@FShrike I just want to show that it is true for n is large enough, but it seems that it is not true

@Snoop Yes, but we require that the density is continuous, and the random walk does not satisfiy this condition.

@JohnBarber I just want to fix n, then let n tend to infty, and prove that the equation holds, but it requires that the density function should be symmetric.

I think you have a typo in your very first equation: The upper limit of the sum should be $n$ rather than $\infty$.

@Gangmen a random walk is defined as a sum of IID nontrivial random variables
